# Consistency of the SKI calculus as unprovability of S = K

Tags: computer-science, combinatory-logic

The exercise I'm dealing with asks me to show that by adding $S = K$ to the usual reduction rules for the SKI-calculus, one obtains an inconsistent equivalence. This must be done without using Böhm's theorem.

Now, I've found two terms (not combinators) $M$ and $N$ with the following properties:

- $M = x$
- $N = y$
- $M$ can be obtained from $N$ by replacing one or more occurrences of $S$ with $K$

From the rule $S = K$ we thereby get that $M = N$, and hence that $x = y$. Which means that any term can be proved equal to any other.

Do you think such an answer could work? Actually, Böhm's theorem (as shown in the book I am studying) establishes that, for distinct combinators $G$ and $H$, there is a combinator $D$ such that $DxyG = x$ and $DxyH = y$. So, I feel it would have been more appropriate to find a combinator $D$ such that $Dx_1x_2S = x_i$ and $Dx_1x_2K = x_j$ with $i, j = 1, 2$ and $i \neq j$. But I have HUGE problems in finding combinators, so I have only found terms respectively reducing to one of the variables, and obtainable one from another by replacing $S$ with $K$ or viceversa.

Comment: You want to prove $x = y$ for any two terms $x$ and $y$. Show (by normalization) that $SKyx = x$ and $KKyx = Kx$, so that $x = Kx$ (because $S=K$ and thus $SKyx = KKyx$). Hence, $Kx = KKx = K$, hence $K = Kx = x$. Similarly, $K = y$, so that $x = K = y$.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. But I asked whether my solution worked as well.

Comment: Ah! Are you asking for a constructive proof of Böhm's theorem? (I probably cannot help with that, but I'm just asking for a clarification of the question.)

Comment: Nope. I asked whether my solution worked. It consisted in finding to terms obtainable one from another by replacing $S$ with $K$, one reducing to x and the other reducing to y.

Comment: Ah! That's a nice question.

Comment: Since M can be obtained from N by replacing S with K, for the rule S = K they are equal. Then x = y for every x and y...no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31057/discussion-between-antonio-piccolomini-daragona-and-darij-grinberg).